# GdkEventButton when migrating from gtkmm-3.0 to gtkmm-4.0

Tags: c++, gtkmm4

I'm trying to get the cursor's coordinates and what type of click occurred when clicking on a button in gtkmm 4.0.

In gtkmm 3.0, I could use `GdkEventButton`, as in this example from the [docs](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/gtkmm-tutorial.html#sec-xeventsignals):

```
bool on_button_press(GdkEventButton* event);
Gtk::Button button("label");
button.signal_button_press_event().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&on_button_press) );
```

But `GdkEventButton` seems to no longer exist or no longer be accessible in gtkmm 4.0.

There is a reference to GdkEvent API changes in the [migration documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html), but I still do not understand how to migrate that example code.

I've made a few unsuccessful blind attempts that probably aren't helpful to reproduce here (e.g. swapping out `GdkEventButton` with `GdkEvent` in the example). Is anyone more familiar or has any sort of related example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Kjell linking [these](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm-documentation/-/blob/master/examples/book/menus/popup/examplewindow.cc) relevant gtkmm 4.0 [examples](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm-documentation/-/blob/master/examples/book/popover/examplewindow.cc), as well as the general advice:

> In most (perhaps all) situations where event signals have been used in
> gtkmm3, use one of the many subclasses of Gtk::EventController.

So to answer the specific question of how to convert this gtkmm 3.0 example:

```
bool on_button_press(GdkEventButton* event);
Gtk::Button button("label");
button.signal_button_press_event().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&on_button_press) );
```

In gtkmm 4.0 it would be something like this:

```
void on_button_press(int n_press, double x, double y);
Gtk::Button button("label");
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::GestureClick> refGesture = Gtk::GestureClick::create();
refGesture->signal_pressed().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_button_pressed));
button.add_controller(refGesture);
```